# select2 multiple -- weird effect when loading data from the server

Tags: html, jquery-select2

When I use a Select2 Multiple (with data loaded from the server during initialization), it always shows the underlying HTML multiline component, then the Select2 takes its final state. It's a weird, annoying and visible effect. If I don't use the "multiple" option, everything is fine -- check the video..

https://youtu.be/Yl5KlT4QWq8

I'm using the latest version of the component, with Bootstrap 4. The same happens in FF, Edge, Safari

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution: remove the multiple="multiple" in the  HTML element, and specifying "mutiple: true" in the Select2 setup call.